# $0$-th moment of product of gaussian and sinc function

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

I would like to calculate the following integrals:

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad \left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x)}{\pi ax}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\,dx$$
2. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad \left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x\pm\pi)}{\pi ax\pm\pi}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2) \,dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: is there anything you want from us?

Comment: try to use function Ei, if you want some help...

Comment: One can use the same idea as in your previous question, except that one has to integrate w.r.t. parameter instead of differentiating.

Comment: ok..thanks..I tried to solve the second case in the previous question and it turns to be equal to the first case. Is that correct? Now I'll try to do the 0-th moment.

Comment: If you need only the answer, I can calculate it with help of Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov yes please.

Comment: @JFNJr See my answer. Unfortunately, Mathematica was able to evaluate only the first integral.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the following answers with help of Wolfram Mathematica 8.0:

1. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{sin(\pi a x)}{\pi a x}\right) e^{-b x^2} dx = \frac1{a^2 \cdot \pi^\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \left( -\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{b} \cdot e^{-\frac{a^2 \cdot \pi^2}{b}} + a \cdot \pi^\frac{3}{2} \cdot \operatorname{Erf}\left( \frac{\pi a}{\sqrt{b }} \right) \right)$ only if $\operatorname{Re}(b) > 0$ and $a \ge 0$, where $\operatorname{Erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$
2. Unfortunately, Mathematica falls to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{sin(\pi a x)}{\pi a x + \pi}\right)^2 e^{-b x^2} dx$

Hope, it helps.